# crear un objeto por consola

Tags: objeto

Estoy aprendiendo Java y POO.
Tengo una clase Alumno con sus atrubutos, nombre,dni,correo.
Quiero preguntar por consola si quiere ingresar un nuevo alumno. 1 Si, 0 No.
Ingreso en el ciclo. Si es afirmativo tengo que instanciar un objeto tipo clase, luego setear cada uno de sus atributos. Todo pedido por consola. Ingrese el nombre, ingrese el dni y luego correo. una vez que esto sucedio, lo almaceno en un ArrayList con la idea de tener un iterator y recorrerlo.
Problema . como nombro el objeto tipo clase Alumno si el nombre es un string. Tengo que ir cambiado el nombre del objeto en cada ciclo.
Hice justo procedimiento crearObjeto con un parametro de tipo string pero no puedo usar ese string y despues decirle que sera un objeto(a no ser que haya un cast), y no veo estetico que el usuario ponga, usuario1 cuando llames el procedimiento. Espero que se entienda.
Saludos

Comment: Tú le pides la información al usuario y con esa información creas la instancia del objeto, pasando en el constructor el dato suministrado (el nombre del alumno o lo que sea). De todos modos, muestra el código que has intentado y dinos qué problemas o errores tienes o que no entiendes en ese código.

Comment: lo re pico de nuevo y lo paso creo que tenia un problema de compresion de clases y objetos. gracias

Answer (score 0):

en respuesta a tu pregunta he desarrollado la lógica que planetas.

**Clase Alumno**

```
public class Alumno {
    
    private String nombre;
    private String dni;
    private String correo;
    
    
    
    //Constructor por parámetros
    public Alumno(String nombre, String dni, String correo) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.correo = correo;
    }
    
    
    //Métodos get y set para los atributos
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }
    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }
    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }
    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }
    

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CrearAlumnos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        //Con un objeto de esta clase puedes pedir por consola datos al usuario
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        System.out.println("QUIERES CREAR UN ALUMNO " + "\n" + "0. No" + "\n" + "1. Si");
        
        int respuesta = sc.nextInt();
        
        //Aquí se encuentra la lógica que mencionas
        if(respuesta == 0) {
            
            System.out.println("PROGRAMA TERMINADO");
        }
        
        else if(respuesta == 1) {
            
            System.out.println("DAME EL NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO");
            String nombre = sc.next();
            
            
            System.out.println("DAME EL DNI DEL ALUMNO");
            String dni = sc.next();
            
            
            System.out.println("DAME EL CORREO DEL ALUMNO");
            String correo = sc.next();
            
            //Se crea el alumno con los parámetros
            Alumno alumnoCreado = new Alumno(nombre, dni, correo);
            
            //Se crea la lista de tipo Alumno 
            //RECUERDA IMPORTAR EL ArrayList del paquete java.util
            ArrayList<Alumno> alumnosCreados = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
            
            //Se mete a tu alumno en la lista creada de tipo Alumno
            alumnosCreados.add(alumnoCreado);
            
            for (Alumno alumno : alumnosCreados) {
                
                System.out.println("Alumno en lista: " + "\n" + "Nombre: " + alumno.getNombre() 
                + "\n" + "DNI: " + alumno.getDni() 
                + "\n" + "Correo: " + alumno.getCorreo());
                System.out.println("------------------------");
            }

        }
        
        else {
            //En caso de introducir otro número se sale del programa
            System.out.println("OTRO NUMERO INTRODUCIDO");
        }

    }

}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Intenta por favor subir el progreso que hayas conseguido desarrollando el programa en el que tengas dudas en tu próxima pregunta.

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la pronta respuesta. Tenia el codigo pero solo deje la clase para plantearmelo de nuevo. No obstante voy a subir el codigo que tenia pero con los ajustes que me comentaste. Como soy nuevo te hago otra consulta que es lo que creo me estaba llevando. si estoy en un ciclo el objeto que haga en la primera vuelta lo guardo en el Array, luego en la segunda vuelta no tendria que renombrar el nuevo objeto. No es asi?

Comment: En ninguna de las siguientes iteraciones tienes que renombrarlo, ya que a cada vuelta del bucle el objeto es considerado como uno nuevo independientemente del nombre de la variable.

Comment: Asi es DQSXE. despues de refrescar me di cuenta.Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aca les dejo la solucion. gracias a los que comentaron. Tal como lo pense mientras me daba un baño mas el apoyo del codigo de DQSXE. No obstante pido si lo revisan me comenten.La creacion del objeto no interfiere

```
package Clases;


public class Alumno {
private String nombre;
private long dni;

public Alumno() {
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public long getDni() {
    return dni;
}

public void setDni(long dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

}
```

/************************************/

```
    package Clases;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int respuesta=0;
  
  Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
  ArrayList<Alumno> alumnosCreados = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
  
     System.out.print("Desea ingresar un alumno:");
     respuesta= teclado.nextInt();
     while (respuesta==1) {             
         Alumno nuevoAlumno=new Alumno();
         
         System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre:");
         nuevoAlumno.setNombre(teclado.next());
         
         System.out.print("Ingrese el dni:");
         nuevoAlumno.setDni(teclado.nextInt());
         
         alumnosCreados.add(nuevoAlumno);
         
         System.out.print("Desea ingresar un alumno:");
        respuesta= teclado.nextInt();
     }
         for (Alumno alumno : alumnosCreados) {
            
            System.out.println("Alumno en lista: " + "\n" + "Nombre: " + alumno.getNombre() 
            + "\n" + "DNI: " + alumno.getDni() 
            + "\n" );
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        } 
     
     
     }
      
   }
```